# MediaMetadataRetriever returns null but fine with MediaStore

Tags: android, metadata

I am a newbie in developing android apps.
I'm developing a music player and would like to get song name, artist, album name, album art from the metadata of audio files.
I have used `MediaMetadataRetriever` but it is slow when there are 800+ songs and returns null for some files while other music players can retrieve those information.

Then I use `MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI` to get song name, artist, album name and `MediaStore.Audio.Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI` to get the album art.

Is there any uri to get (song name, artist, album name, album art) at the same time?
As I need to create a song object in my program.

Below is my code, but it is very slow as it asks for album art for each song.

```
    public ArrayList<Songs> getPlayList(Context c) {

    String[] TRACK_PROJ = {
            MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.ARTIST,
            MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE,
            MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.ALBUM,
            MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.YEAR,
            MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA
    };
    Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    Cursor cursor = c.getContentResolver().query(uri, TRACK_PROJ, null, null, null);

    int count;

    if (cursor != null) {
        count = cursor.getCount();
        if (count > 0) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            do {
                Songs song;
                String artist = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(TRACK_PROJ[0]));
                String title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(TRACK_PROJ[1]));
                String album = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(TRACK_PROJ[2]));
                String year = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(TRACK_PROJ[3]));
                String path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(TRACK_PROJ[4]));
                if (path.toLowerCase().contains(MEDIA_PATH.toLowerCase())) {
                    song = new Songs(artist, title, album, year, path);
                    songsList.add(song);
                }
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        cursor.close();
    }

    for (Songs aSongsList : songsList) {

        String[] ALBUM_PROJ = {MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ART};
        String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM + "=?";
        String[] values = new String[]{aSongsList.getAlbum()};
        Cursor cur = c.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, ALBUM_PROJ, selection, values, null);
        int cnt;
        if (cur != null) {
            cnt = cur.getCount();
            if (cnt > 0) {
                cur.moveToFirst();
                do {
                    String art = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ALBUM_PROJ[0]));
                    if (art != null)
                        aSongsList.setAlbumArt(art);
                } while (cur.moveToNext());
                cur.close();
            }
        }
    }

    return songsList;
}
```

EDIT: (Code of using `MediaMetadataRetriever`)

```
    private Songs getMetadata (File file){
    String artist, title, album, path;
    MediaMetadataRetriever metaRetriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
    metaRetriever.setDataSource(file.getPath());

    try {

        artist = metaRetriever
                .extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST);

        album = metaRetriever
                .extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM);

        path = file.getPath();

        title = metaRetriever
                .extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_TITLE);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        artist = "Unknown";
        title = "Unknown";
        album = "Unknown";
        path = "Unknown";
    }
```

Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Thanks for you reply:) I have used MediaMetadataRetriever before using MediaStore but it returns null for some files while other music player can retrieve those information correctly. The implementation code of using MediaMetadataRetriever is same as yours. Any idea? Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you know this - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.html

```
MediaMetadataRetriever metaRetriver;
metaRetriver = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
metaRetriver.setDataSource("/sdcard/audio.mp3");

try {
        byte [] art = metaRetriver.getEmbeddedPicture();
        Bitmap songImage = BitmapFactory
            .decodeByteArray(art, 0, art.length);
        metaRetriver.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM));
        String artist = metaRetriver
                .extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST));
        String genre = metaRetriver
                .extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_GENRE));
    } catch (Exception e) {
         // TO-DO Exception
    }
```

You would be interested for other available options in above API.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out MediaMetadataRetriever only processes all the data in an MP3 file that is UTF-16

Some of (a lot really) of my MP3s were old and when made for some reason were ISO-8859-1

Using MP3Tag. I made sure the option ID3v2.3 UTF-16 was selected.

[Verify Saving as UTF-16](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYmW8.png)

And then selected all the MP3 Files that I had that were ISO-8859-1 and save (or resave) them

If you are not sure if you are having this problem. You can create a Column tag in MP3 to show the encoding

[Create MP3 Tag Column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fn0ct.png)

[See Files with wrong Encoding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3zk0.png)

After resaving all my MP3's that had ISO-8859-1 as UTF-16 Now MediaMetadataRetriever  NEVER returns Nulls and always returns the proper data.

BobVal