# Why does MediaMetadataRetriever return null for some keys but not when i query MediaStore

Tags: java, android

When i use the `MediaMetaDataRetriever` to get information about a media file it returns **null** for `METADATA_KEY_TITLE`, `METADATA_KEY_ARTIST` and `METADATA_KEY_ALBUM`.

Only METADATA_KEY_DURATION returns a value.

When i use the exact same audio file but instead of using `MediaMetaDataRetriever` i query the `MediaStore` for this information with these columns.

```
MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE
MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST
```

Both return a value but when i looked up these **MediaStore Columns** in the docs it says:

> Indexed value of MediaMetadataRetriever#METADATA_KEY_TITLE extracted
>   from this media item.
>   Indexed value of
>   MediaMetadataRetriever#METADATA_KEY_ARTIST or ExifInterface#TAG_ARTIST
>   extracted from this media item.

So why is it that `MediaStore` does return a value when `MediaMetadataRetriever` does not return a value,  even when it's supposed to do so because as it says in the docs, **MediaStore columns** return an **Indexed value of MediaMetadataRetriever**.

**Edit**

I checked the media file with **mp3tag** on my pc and noticed that there are no values set for the title and artist fields so that's why it returns null with `MediaMetaDataRetriever`.

But how is it then possible that the column `MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE` does return a value for this media file and `MediaMetaDataRetriever` doesn't?

As i already stated above, `MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE` returns an

> Indexed value of MediaMetadataRetriever#METADATA_KEY_TITLE extracted
>   from this media item.

Comment: It's just a guess, but maybe android is taking the *song fingerprints* of the files and checking if they match in a database. Then it could infer and store the metadata in the MediaStore. This, of course, leaves the file unmodified and creates the behavior you describe.  As a side note, my Pixel 2 has utilizes a database to show the current playing song in the room, so maybe it's using similar technology here.

Comment: Can you please tell what was returned from MediaStore?

Comment: In addition, please look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21705876/mediametadataretriever-returns-null-but-fine-with-mediastore especially in the last answer. Maybe this information can help you

Comment: @RefaelJan MediaStore returns the Title and Artist from the media file when i query for the title and aritst columns and MediaMetadataRetriever returns null for METADATA_KEY_TITLE and METADATA_KEY_ARTIST but as i already wrote in my post above, these MediaStore columns return Indexed values of MediaMetadataRetriever so that's why it's weird that MediaStore works and MediaMetadataRetriever not.

Comment: @RefaelJan Already read that post which didn't have an answer to my problem.